# Preventing many if and else conditions in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table (mysql) which contains five columns `(id,people,gender, age and years)`, each column contains different values which is listed below,

```
id | people | gender | age | year |
 1 |  Mark  | M      | 10  | 2010 |
 2 |  luke  | F      | 20  | 2014 |
```

With this data I want to make some queries from the table depending on a specified condition.
Below are the conditions

```
I want to 
1. select all people from the table.
2. select people from the  where gender is M.
3. select people from the table where gender is M and Year is 2010.
4. select people from the table where age is 10 and gender is M and year is 2010
5. select people from the table where age is 20.
6. select people from the table where year is 2014.
7. select people from the table where year is 2010 and age is 10.
```

I am using php script to call data from mysql table.
You see this many specified conditions calling the data, I want to be able to execute them from one script when the condition is selected from a form. The problem is using many `if and else conditions` to execute them, I want to know if there is another option to prevent specifying many `if and else conditions` to execute the conditions above.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: no. if you have multiple conditions, you need multiple ifs() to handle those conditions. it's unavoidable. if you're using code that makes decisions, then you're using `if()` tests.

Comment: Never record the age of a population! Store the birthdate and do maths with it!

Comment: Alright @ Marc B, I thought my ifs are too many and it is not the standard way of doing this. Thanks

Comment: @ Nicholas Henrard,please this is just a sample to illustrate my problem. Thanks anyway

Comment: You can use switch with condition flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you can do something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT
            id,
            people, 
            gender,
            age,
            years
          FROM
            table
          ";

$clause = array();

if(isset($selection['age'])) $clause[] = 'age = %d';
if(isset($selection['gender'])) $clause[] = 'gender = %s';
if(isset($selection['year'])) $clause[] = 'year = %d';

$whereclause = implode(' and ', $clause);

if(count($clause) > 0) $query .= 'WHERE '.$whereclause;
```

if your $selection contains more the one, e.g. age and gender the result would be:

```
'age = %d and gender = %s'
```

Comment: Please I don't really understand, can you explain further. I am executing many different sql queries.Thanks

Comment: I used to call $clause $conditions :) For the rest exactly the same as my solution. @George instead of 'genderquery' you should read `"gender = '".mysql_real_escape_string($selection['gender'])."'"`

Comment: @ winkbrace, I am using prepared statements to prevent all sql injections so I think I am safe. Thanks

Comment: @ Raphael Muller,is it possible to use this for querying data from two tables?

Comment: @George: It depends on your query. But normally it should. You have to append the tablenames. like: `\`table1\`.\`age\`` and also use the correct join syntax in your from clause.

Comment: Ok. But please i am finding it difficult to workaround it because i have three tables and I am using JOIN syntax to call the data from the tables depending on a condition. Some conditions take data from two tables and others the three tables and even a table.

Comment: do you have the layout and the query you want perform?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55985/discussion-between-george-and-raphael-muller).